# To use SSL should my JAR file be signed?

Tags: java, ssl, jar, applet, digital-signature

I have a SSL applet I want to connect to a Cpp server.  Do I need to self sign the JAR at all?  Also do I absolutely need to set up a CA to do it?

I had some luck with trust stores in the past. Do I need a trust/key store to get it working?  If so can you please link me a decent page on how to do it?

Comment: I'm hoping I don't need a trust/key store in order to get it working but I will have to live with it if it's needed

Answer (score 2):

The difference between signed and unsigned applets is that unsigned applets runs in a security sandbox and is restricted in what they can do. The can make http connections to the server they was loaded from. The can not make http connections to other servers.

So it is not neccesary to sign the applet provided that you host the applet on the server you want to connect to.

Using SSL is a neccesary if you want the connection between the server and the applet to be secure.

Comment: Does the class file need to be in a JAR?

Comment: Can my applet make SSL socket connections (not HTTP) to the server it was loaded from?

Comment: No, the class file does not have to live in a jar, but you should if you have more than one class file. Remember that the browser will set up one http connection for each class file unless you put them in a jar file.

Comment: Yes, you may make ssl connections to the server. In fact, you may create any kind of connection using any protocol.

Comment: I think I need a truststore though... think so?  Are there any signs that I need one I could recognise?

Comment: If the applet should connect to an ssl encrypted site, then the applet will need a truststore for the ssl certificate.

Comment: The applet will be connecting to a Cpp server on port 12120 using SSL.  I put the truststore in the Applet's JAR file right?  One last thing... I only put the certificate in the truststore not the private key right (I know but I thought I'd ask). Ooh too, you specify what trust store you are using on the command line, correct? Sorry for the bulky reply.

Comment: You must put the trustore in the jar file. Do NOT put the private key there. You don't have any command line when running applets in a browser. You must specify the truststore in the java code using the api that the http connection library provides.

Comment: Hmm, are you certain I can find API code to do that using sockets?